# Phrase suggestion on Xiosis Scribe 2011

Tags: software

I have downloaded Scribe from [www.xiosis.com](http://www.xiosis.com) and have been giving it a go. So far its all its advertised to be.

My question is I have written a long article on Scribe and phrase suggestion is not suggesting phrases from the document. Its just suggesting normal word completion. Type assist enabled.

If you can shed some light on how to enable phrase completion I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Writers community - does this question fall foul of our policy that [word processing questions belong on SU](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/276/should-this-site-help-with-specific-writing-software-questions), or is Scribe like Scrivener - a special exception because it is focused on Writers?  It lists itself on its website as word processing software, but lists Scrivener in its comparison chart.

Comment: This is about how to get the software to help with the process of writing... I'm okay with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scribe learns the phrases from the document when the document is saved. To have Scribe suggest phrases for completion from your article, simply click 'save' and save it. Auto saving does not count.